# GNUPG2 Dependency Error Trying to Install NordVPN on Bionic Beaver 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, vpn, gnupg

New to Ubuntu/Linux, and having an issue. I'm trying to set up NordVPN on 18.04.1 Bionic Beaver, and I try to use the 4 install steps on the website here:

https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/

...and when I run the first command, I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get install /home/ubuntu/Downloads/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'nordvpn-release' instead of '/home/ubuntu/Downloads/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nordvpn-release : Depends: gnupg2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So it seems I have a dependency issue regarding GNUPG2? So I followed with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnupg2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  gpgv gpgsm gnupg-l10n gnupg dirmngr

E: Package 'gnupg2' has no installation candidate
```

...followed by:

```
sudo apt show gnupg
Package: gnupg
Version: 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Source: gnupg2
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GnuPG Maintainers <pkg-gnupg-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 370 kB
Depends: dirmngr (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gnupg-l10n (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gnupg-utils (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpg (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpg-agent (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpg-wks-client (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpg-wks-server (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpgsm (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gpgv (= 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1)
Suggests: parcimonie, xloadimage
Breaks: debsig-verify (<< 0.15), dirmngr (<< 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1), gnupg2 (<< 2.1.11-7+exp1), libgnupg-interface-perl (<< 0.52-3), libgnupg-perl (<= 0.19-1), libmail-gnupg-perl (<= 0.22-1), monkeysphere (<< 0.38~), php-crypt-gpg (<= 1.4.1-1), python-apt (<= 1.1.0~beta4), python-gnupg (<< 0.3.8-3), python3-apt (<= 1.1.0~beta4), software-properties-common (<= 0.96.24.3)
Replaces: gnupg2 (<< 2.1.11-7+exp1)
Homepage: https://www.gnupg.org/
Task: ubuntu-desktop, mail-server, cloud-image, samba-server, server, kubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop-share, lubuntu-gtk-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-qt-core, lubuntu-qt-desktop, lubuntu-qt-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 249 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
Description: GNU privacy guard - a free PGP replacement
 GnuPG is GNU's tool for secure communication and data storage.
 It can be used to encrypt data and to create digital signatures.
 It includes an advanced key management facility and is compliant
 with the proposed OpenPGP Internet standard as described in RFC4880.
 .
 This package contains the full suite of GnuPG tools for cryptographic
 communications and data storage.

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

Source: gnupg2?

Are there any suggestions on how I can go about fixing this gnupg2 dependency issue and install NordVPN before I try the longer install process where I'm assuming I'm going to run into this if not more issues? Or anything I can try? I'd rather use the latest Ubuntu and not have to downgrade. And I can't be the only one experiencing this. I've re-installed 18.04 twice now from the Ubuntu site. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue and it was resolved by running `apt-get update` prior to installing `gnupg`.